# Database concept multilanguage

Tags: php, sql, database, cakephp

I want to create a site in PHP with cakephp that users can insert product manually.
The problem is for the multilanguage because I can have into my site users from all over the world and the product 'apple' in italian for example is 'mela'.
Consider that I can have many many data!
Then i have some solution for the database:

1. - Create a table products with an id
   - Create a table product_aliases where I have an id the id of product language and the text(ex. apple) 
     In this mode users can enter into 'apple', translate ad I insert a new line into product_aliases with same id product different language and different text but same product
2. Define 5 language and create a table with more fields (title_en, title_it, title_es...) the translation is in the same record
   Only one table but restricted language
3. - Create a table products with an id
   - Create a table for every language that i want for example: prducts_en, products_it where I can store my data with same foreign key to the product but divide from language to make fast query.

Other solution are accepted!! 
I never work with large multilanguage database help me and tell me what is the best solution for my database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one is the correct solution in general.

It's used in many enterprise applications: a table with an id field for identification of the not multilanguage information (example: unit price for a product) and a table with a row for every combination product/language.

The second one is against every db normalization rule.

The third one is a different derivation of the second one, and if you use an index on the language column in the translated labels table you should not have a great disadvantage in terms of performance.

If you need I will explain better!

Comment: I need a fast database when I retrieve data and with thiusand and thousand of product I don't know which solution is better

Comment: Open source? Thought about MySql? For the above I can tell you it's been four years I've been working with these products and they are really efficent if you leverage the indexes system.

Comment: But which is for you the best solution?

Comment: MySql is good enough for many uses: many big enterprises use it as an easy to configure back end. You have the advantage of a relational database which is at the moment easier to leverage in a short amount of time. BTW, thousands of rows can be managed on a commodity hardware. What are your requirements in terms of amount of data? Do you have any projection?!

Comment: Well, MySQL is also used at Twitter (http://engineering.twitter.com/2012/04/mysql-at-twitter.html) so I think it could leverage some big amount of data. It all depends about how much data (millions, billions?) you are going to store.

Comment: I'm using mysql already with php (cakephp mvc) but i'm not sure which of these solution is better if I have to store  milion of product in multilanguage